# Twitter-Bootstrap in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Has anybody used twitter bootstrap and deployed application in production? Can you direct me to some resources? I watched railscasts but if there are any blogs which gives detail explanation. Are there any other option for frontend other than twitter bootstrap? Also, is there any javascript option?

Comment: Bootstrap is CSS and JavaScript (client side) and Rails is server side.  Are you asking for tutorials on how to use external stylesheets and JavaScript in your Rails views?

Comment: yes. tutorials on how to use external stylesheets and JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I enjoyed reading this Articles from Ruby Source:

http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/

http://rubysource.com/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstrap%E2%80%99s-design-in-a-rails-app/

Also, if you just want to customize the look of TB, check http://stylebootstrap.info/

Here is a huge list of bootstrap extensions / plugins:
http://www.bootstraphero.com/the-big-badass-list-of-twitter-bootstrap-resources

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing: Bootstrap is not a front-end. It is a way to get started on the design of your site by creating a decent-looking starting point. It is mainly CSS (well, LESS) with a few optional JavaScript additions to add extra UI functionality.

If you're actually interested in building a front end to a Rails app, you may be interested in [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). Backbone is a way to link up your HTML DOM with your data (from Rails), and is great for single-page apps which don't require page refreshes every time you do anything. A good starting place for learning Backbone is Code School's [Anatomy of Backbone](http://backbone.codeschool.com/) tutorials. Coincidentally, Code School also offer many other courses you might like.

Comment: does it work with Rails 3.2.3? I am not sure because it is not picking default css values (e.g width). I am using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Answer (score 1):

To link CSS and JavaScripts to your view, you can use [Asset Tag Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#asset-tag-helpers).

As an example:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
```

would generate tags linking to `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css`, if those are the names of the files.

`javascript_include_tag` pulls scripts relative to `app/assets/javascripts`
`stylesheet_link_tag` pulls stylesheets relative to `app/assets/stylesheets`

If you want to reference a file in a directory structure (i.e. assets are not in the root of the above folders), you can link relative to those root folders:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/bootstrap/bootstrap-min" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/bootstrap/bootstrap" %>
```

These tags would reference `app/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/bootstrap-min.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css`.

To apply styles, you would then use the stylesheet classes and ids in bootstrap.css.  For instance, the button to fork Twitter's bootstrap looks like

```
<a href="https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/" 
   class="btn btn-primary btn-large">View project on GitHub</a>
```

You would use a [URL Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to "View project on GitHub", 
             "https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/", 
             :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
```

edit:

If you are looking at the code on Github and confused about the `.less` extension, that is because Bootstrap uses a CSS generation framework called Less. You'll need to run `make bootstrap` and be sure you have `lessc` installed.  Or, you can download the already compiled framework [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip).

Comment: Based on the poster's comment on another answer, this may not be relevant (twitter-bootstrap-gem is being used). I will leave this because I think it is relevant for the learning process based on the question as it is.